# How to refactor a sequence of add-to-list calls into a let?

Tags: elisp

I'm basically looking to refactor the below:

```el
(eval-after-load 'find-file-in-project
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.clj")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.erb")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.haml")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "Gemfile*")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.css")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.scss")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.sass")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.rake")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.thor")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "Capfile")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.gemspec")
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns "*.yml")
     ))
```

Into something nice where I define the list of file extensions once and then cons them to the `ffip-patterns` variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "into a let"? A let binding has a temporary local scope. You're talking about a change to the global value of a list. You can certainly refactor the original code, but not "into a let".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not worried about duplicates in the list (which `add-to-list` checks for), you can add the elements with `append`:

```
(eval-after-load 'find-file-in-project
  '(setq ffip-patterns (append (list "*.clj" "*.erb") ffip-patterns)))
```

Otherwise, you can iterate through the extensions with `dolist`:

```
(eval-after-load 'find-file-in-project
  '(dolist (pattern (list "*.clj" "*.erb"))
     (add-to-list 'ffip-patterns pattern)))
```

Comment: I went with the second version, it works well. Thanks!